# PHP regex find value in string

Tags: php, regex, string-matching

Ok, since I never really got an hang on regex in PHP, it would be awesome if someone could link to a understandable article...

In this case i want to find a value in a string.

if example

```
$string = "blah blah blha lorem ipsum [get_this_value=10] more lorem ipsum";
```

i would like a function that returns "10". it would be loverly if it was stored in array and that the function can retrieve many of them if there's multiple of these i want them in an array.

```
$string = "blah blah blha lorem ipsum [get_this_value=10] more lorem ipsum [get_this_value=9] etc etc";
```

would return array(10, 9) and so on...

Comment: Best source for RegEx online is [http://www.regexbuddy.com/regex.html](http://www.regexbuddy.com/regex.html) If you can afford it ($30) RegExBuddy is worth every penny and will pay for itself in productivity in a very short period of time.

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you with regex but I'm getting better thanks to starting to watch this series: http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/regular-expressions-for-dummies/  You wanted an article, these are videos but they start from the very basics and work up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should learn about regular expressions. I can highly recommend [this tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Then you can read up on some PHP specific regex issues in [PHP's documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

But to get you started, this would solve your problem:

```
preg_match_all("/\[[^\]=]*=(\d+)\]/", $string, $matches);
```

Now `$matches[1]` will be your desired array. Note that this does not depend on the specific string `get_this_value`.

For the purpose of you actually teaching yourself some regular expressions through the linked pages, I will not explain this regex in detail, but instead just tell you the concepts I have used. Unescaped square brackets `[...]` mark a **character class**. In this case (due to the `^`) a **negated** one. `\d` is a **built-in character class**. `+` is a **repetition quantifier**. And parentheses `(...)` mark a **capturing group**.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$string = "blah blah blha lorem ipsum [get_this_value=10] more lorem [get_this_value=13] ipsum";

preg_match_all("~\[get_this_value=(\d+)\]~i", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
/*

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [get_this_value=10]
            [1] => [get_this_value=13]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 13
        )

)
*/
```

Comment: It doesn't hurt ;). But thanks for pointing it out, I removed it.